# angular 2 threejs FirstPersonControls

Tags: angular, three.js

any idea in how to import and use the threeJS FirstPersonControl in a Angular 2 app.

My goal is the possibility to fly inside and outside geometries loaded into the scene.

My application already implements the OrbitControls so I assume I will need to disable all mouse functionalities.

Any simple code will be very appreciated.

Thank you,

Dino

**UPDATE**

This is my code for importing and using the **OrbitControls** in a angular 2 app:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

declare const require: (moduleId: string) => any;

const OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE);

//in component implementation
this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.aCamera, this.aRenderer.domElement);
```

from here I get really confused. If I do not import anything else, my editor allows me to write:

```
this.flyControls = new THREE.FlyControls(this.aCamera, this.aRenderer.domElement);
```

code compiles with no error hence I assumed the FlyControls are embedded into the three library but I must be wrong as I receive the following error:

> **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_three**.FlyControls is not a constructor ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:

so I have downloaded the npm library into my angular app like this:

```
npm install three-fly-controls
```

now my package.json looks like:

> "three": "0.85.0",
>   "three-fly-controls": "1.1.0", 
>   "three-orbit-controls": "82.1.0",

and wrote same code as the code written for my OrbitControls:

```
const MyFlyControls = require('three-fly-controls')(THREE);

//in component implementation
this.controls2 = new MyFlyControls(this.aCamera, this.aRenderer.domElement);
```

and again got the error:

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline
>   template:6:0 caused by: MyFlyControls is not a constructor

what am I missing? How am I suppose to import the FlyControls or FirstPersonControls into an angular 2 project?

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried?

Comment: Since you have OrbitControls working, you ought to be able to change out the controls class with the first person controls class. All of the example controls classes can be had by doing an npm or bower install of three.js OR by going directly to git and finding the controls here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js/controls PointerLock controls are also similar and an example can be found at https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for your help but I am still struggling as Flycontrols does not seem to work like OrbitControls, please see UPDATE section in my question

Comment: any solution? struggling as well... orbit controls is imported very well but couldn't find a way to import and use the first-person controls...